# Issue with "refetchQueries" not working in production

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I'm encountering an issue with "refetchQueries" in my Next.js app with Apollo Client. In development mode, it works as expected but in production, it stops working.

Here's some background information: I have a Next.js project and an API that uses Apollo Server. In the Next.js app, I'm using Apollo Client to make queries and mutations. When I make a mutation, I use "refetchQueries" to refetch a specific query to update the data. This works perfectly fine in development mode, but when I deploy to production, sometimes it refetches the query, sometimes it does not.

This is one of the mutations that's failing

```
const [createEventMutation, { loading: isCreatingEventMutation }] = useMutation(
  EVENT_CREATE,
  { refetchQueries: ["EVENTS", "EVENT"] }
);
```

After the mutation, I redirect to a page where I show all the events so it's important to show the newly created event.

I've checked the network logs, and I don't see any errors or timeouts.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with "refetchQueries" not working as expected in production mode? Any suggestions on what could be causing this issue or how to debug it?

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue. In my case, I was re-fetching two queries. In production only one of the queries got re-fetched the other one did not trigger. It worked fine in development.

I have two tabs in the site, tab 1 calls the queries, tab 2 makes mutations and re-fetched the queries.

When I go to tab 2 it seems the queries and their variables go out of scope and it doesn't re-fetch after mutation. I have to pass `variables` along with query in my re-fetch. The same variables used in tab-1.

Only then re-fetch works in tab-2.

Hope I could help.